# Side-by-side blocks using CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-position

I want to have block elements side-by-side. I don't don't want to use `left, right, top`, or anything similar.

#### HTML

```
<div class="iLB">LOLOLOL</div>
<div class="iLB">
    This is content.<br/>
    This is content.<br/>
    This is content.
</div>
<div class="iLB">This, too?</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.iLB {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97wDh/)**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:top;`

```css
.iLB {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}​
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/97wDh/1/

Comment: @ghostmancer: Note that this still gives you inline elements, not block elements.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `display: inline-block` it's actually inline elements. They work just like character boxes, so they are placed side by side on a text line, that's why they line up with their bottom edge at the same height.

You can use `float: left` instead to make them block elements and place them side by side:

http://jsfiddle.net/97wDh/2/

Comment: Using a `float` is unnecessary. He's setting their `display` type to `inline-block`. `float` does not change an elements `display` property to `block`. The problem he's having in his demo is the vertical alignment of the content in those divs

Comment: @Mark: You are mistaken. Making an element float *does* automatically turn it into a block element. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position The OP asked for block element, and what he has now is inline elements.

Comment: he started with block elements, but in order to not use any floats he can set their display property to inline-block. using inline-block and float on a block level element is unnecessary.

Comment: @Mark: Using inline-block and float on an element is not only unnecessary, it's totally pointless, as the element will automatically be a block element. Why do you think that the OP doesn't want to use any floats? Using floats works in more browsers than using inline-block.

Comment: Using floats has its drawbacks as well depending on your markup and surrounding CSS. Such as not clearing floats when necessary. inline-block works in all modern browsers and IE8+ (with a doctype for IE8). The OP needs to specify if IE7 and older is a requirement, which there are hacks for that if so.

Comment: @Mark: Of course floats can have drawbacks too, bit I still don't see why you think that the OP wants to avoid floats.